# \global\bibsep Problem in elsarticle Class

Tags: elsarticle

When I use elsarticle class; see
http://hess.ess.washington.edu/repository/BCO_neon_2019/tex/elsarticle.cls

I get the below errors:

```
! Undefined control sequence, \global\bibsep

! You can't use a prefix with ‘the character = '.<to be read again>= \global\bibsep=
```

How can I fix these errors?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times,10pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel,natbib}

\begin{document}
I am confused.

\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}
\bibliography{Bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's impossible to help without seeing some code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: It is hard to say as you have not posted the real multi-line error message as shown by Tex, but it would appear that earlier you had gone `\let\bibsep=something` so broken all  later uses of `\bibsep`

Comment: please add the document to your question, in a code block so line endings preserved

Comment: your example runs without error in texlive 2021, please show the full log that you get from running that example

Comment: Here is the Log file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sscspURcxFL-OzFrPxkdWwJbIt6dGB80/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm using Texmaker.

Comment: you are using a very old version of elsarticle I used the version that is in texlive (I assume it is also in miktex)  `/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/elsarticle/elsarticle.cls
Document Class: elsarticle 2020/11/20, 3.3: Elsevier Ltd`   although I also get no error  if I use the version that you link to

Comment: that's odd I get (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip51
\bibsep=\skip52
  that is natbib defines bibsep, but you seem to have the same version of natbib butshow no bibsep definition (D:\Users\karee\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/natbib\natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.

Comment: line 339 of `natbib.sty` should say `\newlength{\bibsep}`  what does your file say on that line of `D:\Users\karee\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/natbib\natbib.sty`

Comment: I am sharing the file natbib.sty that I have in my system below
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J3OO2ozf9PmFMy1YavVCnUzuMZ7aZIdL/view?usp=sharing

Line 339 says
\xdef\NAT@sep{\@tempc}\fi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a copy of natbib in which lines 637-641 have been commented out:

```
%\newlength{\bibhang}
%\setlength{\bibhang}{1em}
%\newlength{\bibsep}
% {\@listi \global\bibsep\itemsep \global\advance\bibsep by\parsep}
```

Files in the standard distribution shouldn't be altered in this way.
If  you edited the file, replace it by the original, if you obtained this from some distribution, report it to the distributor.

As this is removing the definition of `\bibsep` you get an error that `\bibsep` is not defined....

Several other parts of the file are similarly commented out.

Comment: I uncommented the lines you mentioned and it solved the problem. However, another problem occurred: Errors with the citations. I then replaced natbib.sty in my system with the one here https://www.cita.utoronto.ca/~matzner/svc/tex/natbib.sty and everything went smooth. You are the man David!

Comment: @Dr.KareemElgindy if you have a new problem post a new question but please next time ensure that (a) you have not got any corrupted files in your standard tex input tree, and include a _complete_ test file _in t hequestion_ (I followed google drive links this time as you are new to the site but normally I would not do that, and in any case it is bad as the question is archived here forever but will not be understandable if the text at those links changes)

Comment: @Dr.KareemElgindy did you edit natbib originally or is miktex distributing a corrupted file?

Comment: Thanks @David Carlise. I'll try my best to abide by those rules. I never changed natbib.sty and never commented any lines there. Actually this is my first time to know even where is it located in my system-- thanks to you. So, surely, this must be a bad corrupted file from the miktex distribution server.

Comment: @Dr.KareemElgindy thanks for confirming

Comment: Thanks @David Carlise, in case this matters, today morning I opened MikTex Console in my Windows 11, clicked on Updates->Check for updates-> Update now.
Later, I clicked on Packages-> searched for natbib -> right click natbib -> update package database. In both cases, I retrieved updates from https://ctan.math. washington.edu.

Comment: @Dr.KareemElgindy I compared your natbib with the one provided by miktex and they are different. Imho you replaced the original at some time by a local version (you also had a local  version of `elsarticle.cls`).